# AppleScript to export script editor script as application

Tags: applescript, automator, script

I have a binary that I want wrapped up as an Application, so I thought this was a good use case for AppleScript.

I want to automate how Script Editor lets you export an AppleScript as a .app bundle. This is what I have so far, I'm confused about how to read the libraries dictionary for the script editor.

```
tell application "Script Editor"

set command to "do shell script " & "\"APP_PATH\""
set innard to {contents: command}
set Tallgeese to make new document with properties innard
save Tallgeese as "application"

end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the full path where you want to save this application.

Here is an example that saves it in the "**Applications**" folder of the user.

```
set appName to "someAppName"
set thePath to (path to applications folder from user domain as string with folder creation) & appName & ".app"
tell application "Script Editor"
    set command to "do shell script " & "\"/bin/ls\""
    set innard to {contents:command}
    set Tallgeese to make new document with properties innard
    compile Tallgeese
    save Tallgeese as "application" in thePath
    close document 1 -- close the document
    -- quit ---- quit the editor
end tell
```

Comment: I get " Script Editor got an error: Can’t get document "someAppName". (-1728)" with this (just changed app_path to /bin/ls)

Comment: Try the edited script

Comment: Yes! Dude you are awesome! Also is there an easy way in Apple Script to add an image for the icon or I can just add that in the app folder with icns.

Comment: Also, when this app crashes as it will since I'm developing it, where does the debug log or exception information go? Currently I'm not seeing anything on stdout or console's logs